# How to check the greater than in condition block in Azure logic app

Tags: azure, conditional-statements, azure-logic-apps

How to compare the dates in condition. Also, if I want to check between condition, what should I do in condition block because it doesn't provide that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this? comparing one date with other

[image]

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if this is what you were looking for ?